# Make Django Admin remember my parameters after posting

Tags: django, search, parameters, django-admin, get

I have a problems thats been bugging me for a while. I want to use dates in django admin to view entries between certain dates. 
To do this I have customized my changelist.html for this model and put a form in there. When posted I override the queryset method like this

```
def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(ModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)

    if request.POST.has_key('date1'):
        return qs.filter(startdate__gte=request.POST['date1']).filter(startdate__lte=request.POST['date2'])               
    return qs
```

This works great but its only one little problem. The parameters are forgotten if I for example choose to sort the result in any way.

If I instead of this type in the url straight into the browser so it looks like this

http//localhost/admin/some/model/?startdate__gte=2010-01-01&startdate__lte=2010-12-30

I can sort however I want to afterwards because they´ll stick just like this 
http//localhost/admin/some/model/?o=5&ot=asc&startdate__lte=2010-12-30&startdate__gte=2010-01-01

Do I need to use a filterspec to solve this?

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0):

There is a change request over at the Django project asking for this functionality.

It's waiting for someone to write tests for the proposed patch before it's committed, so you could either do that or you could download the proposed patch (near the bottom of the page) and use it.

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6903